# Problems making PHP geocoder run

Tags: php

I am trying to make [PHP Geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder#installation) work but the examples I find in internet are very few.
I am also not very familiar with the Composer and this makes things even worse.
This is what I have done till now:

1) Installed the geocoder in my selected folder using composer:

```
composer require willdurand/geocoder
```

2) I try to use [this](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder#usage) example to make geocoder work:
I type inside a PHP file these two lines:

```
$curl     = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps($curl);
```

But I get this error when I execute it:

```
> Fatal error: Class 'Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter' not found in
```

So I guess all these examples are not generalized and for the specific geocoder installation? I have to change the paths?

Comment: Have you installed the Ivory HttpAdapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

just after the opening php tag.